# Windows service Debug Issue

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created windows service i have try to debug for that i use Under debug Tab click on attach to process select Myservice.exe it wont go through the break point.

In service on start  event i was write  following code

```
     protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to terminate ...");
    }
```

Please help me how resolve this issue....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following method.On your code. This is by far the easiest method to set a breakpoint on service library.

**`Debugger.Break();`**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to terminate ...");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like this to prompt to attach a debugger in debug mode:

```
#if DEBUG    
if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Debugger.Launch();
}    
#endif
```

You could even use this code in your main method, it will run the service as a normal application in debug mode:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var service = new YourService();
#if DEBUG
    service.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
    service.Stop();
#else
    var ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { service };
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
}
```